# Reset Cache using ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple cache implemented using a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

How can I reset my cache to avoid concurrence while another thread can be using the cache?

Current solution:

```
    private ConcurrentDictionary<object, TEntity> _cachedItems = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, TEntity>();

    public TEntity GetOrAddCache(object id, Func<object, TEntity> addItem)
    {
        var item = _cachedItems.GetOrAdd(id, addItem).Clone();
        return item;
    }

    public void ResetCachedItems(IList<TEntity> items)
    {
        _cachedItems = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, TEntity>(items.Select(x => x.Clone()).ToDictionary(x => (object)x.Id));
    }
```

Should I add a lock in the `ResetCachedItems`? If yes, why?  Since the `ConcurrentDictionary` is thread-safe and I'm just creating a new instance and pass it to the `_cachedItems`

Note: I'm using a Clone method to keep my cache items read-only.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have the cache items be immutable rather than cloning them every time they are fetched?

Comment: About the Clone, it's a legacy system, I can't make ```TEntity``` immutable. Any thoughts about ```ResetCachedItems```? Thank you

Comment: I dont see any reason to add locking. If anyone calls GetOrAdd while you are reseting they may or may not be adding the item to the old or the new cache. But if it us truly a cache one should never expect to find a hit.

Comment: I didn't understand. What you mean by "But if it us truly a cache one should never expect to find a hit."? Thank you